# Создать в админ меню новую страницу

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет
Мне необходимо создать новую страницу в админ меню, и сабменю. Я это делаю при помощи этого кода

```
add_menu_page(
    esc_html__( 'Welcome', 'mycrmqw' ), //тайтл
    esc_html('My CRM', 'mycrmqw'), //Тайтл в меню
    'manage_options', // указывает что  плагин доступен только админу
    'qweqwe',
    '', //функция которую нужно создать и в ней выводить контент
    'dashicons-art', //иконка
    6 //где будет расположен
);

add_submenu_page(
    'qweqwe',
    'title 1',
    'menu title1',
    'edit_posts',
    'edit.php?post_type=book1'
);
add_submenu_page(
    'qweqwe',
    'title 2',
    'menu title2',
    'edit_posts',
    'edit.php?post_type=genre'
);
```

Но мне необходимо чтобы основной страницы меню небыло, а сразу открывалось первое сабменю

Вот пример http://prntscr.com/zm0pqj

То есть нужно создать страницу, но она просто оболочка для подменюшек

Comment: Картинка должна быть в теле вопроса картинкой, а не ссылкой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который делает то, что вы хотите. Надо для первой `add_submenu_page` указать тот же слаг, что и для `add_menu_page`. В вашем случае - `qweqwe`.

```
function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        esc_html__( 'Easy Real Estate', 'mycrmqw' ), // тайтл.
        esc_html__( 'Easy Real Estate', 'mycrmqw' ), // тайтл в меню.
        'manage_options', // указывает, что  плагин доступен только админу.
        'qweqwe', // слаг меню.
        'mycrmqw_properties', // функция для вывода контента.
        'dashicons-art', // иконка.
        6 // где будет расположена.
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'qweqwe',
        esc_html__( 'Properties', 'mycrmqw' ),
        esc_html__( 'Properties', 'mycrmqw' ),
        'manage_options',
        'qweqwe'
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'qweqwe',
        'title 2',
        'menu title2',
        'edit_posts',
        'edit.php?post_type=genre'
    );
}

function mycrmqw_properties() {
    echo 'Properties';
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
```

Так это выглядит в админке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не совсем то, так как нужно чтобы открывалась страница cpt, а так получается открывается страница  'add_menu_page', решил проблему удалением remove_submenu_page('qweqwe', 'qweqwe');

Comment: Надо сразу в вопросе писать, как нужно

Comment: А если внимательно прочитать вопрос? 
 `Но мне необходимо чтобы основной страницы меню небыло, а сразу открывалось первое сабменю`

Comment: Я вам так и сделал, достаточно внимательно прочитав вопрос. И уж поправить мой код под себя - ваша задача. И запомните, здесь вам никто ничего не должен - это вам нужны ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить проблему удалив сабменю созданной страниц

```
remove_submenu_page('qweqwe', 'qweqwe');
```